# yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<block mapping start>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, rake, exchange-server

I am using the command `rake service:all` for the UI installation. But I find this error and struck for hours.

I have already checked the yaml format from yamllint.com but I could not able to find my error.

frontend.yaml:

```
../config/frontend/env.js:/usr/share/nginx/html/public/env.jsversion: "3.6"

services:
    frontend:
      image: "rubykube/mikroapp:0.1.5"
      volumes: 
        - ../config/frontend/env.js:/usr/share/nginx/html/public/env.js
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.frontend.rule: "PathPrefix:/;Host:www.dexfinpro.com"
      traefik.port: 3000

  tower:
    image: "rubykube/tower:0.1.8"
    volumes:
      - ../config/frontend/tower.js:/home/app/env.js
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.frontend.rule: "PathPrefix:/tower;Host:www.dexfinpro.com"
      traefik.port: 8080
```

ERROR:

> yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<block mapping start>'
>     in "./compose/frontend.yaml", line 3, column 1
>   rake aborted!
>   Command failed with status (1): [docker-compose up -d proxy...]

I found this error.

Comment: The file is not valid. You have incorrect indentation for `frontend` block

Comment: Now i make it in valid format but still find same error @DeepakMahakale

Answer (score 1):

The content in your file is not valid. The reason is you have indented the `frontent` block by 2 more spaces.

You can always check if the yaml is valid or not here - http://www.yamllint.com/

```
services:
  frontend:
    image: "rubykube/mikroapp:0.1.5"
    volumes: 
      - ../config/frontend/env.js:/usr/share/nginx/html/public/env.js
  labels:
    traefik.enable: true
    traefik.frontend.rule: "PathPrefix:/;Host:www.dexfinpro.com"
    traefik.port: 3000

  tower:
    image: "rubykube/tower:0.1.8"
    volumes:
      - ../config/frontend/tower.js:/home/app/env.js
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.frontend.rule: "PathPrefix:/tower;Host:www.dexfinpro.com"
      traefik.port: 8080
```

**Note:** I am not sure  if you wan't the block with `tower` key at top level or inside `services` so make change accordingly

Comment: yamllint.com will tell you that it is invalid, but and that something went wrong while parsing the mapping on line 1, which is essentially useless *and the reason why although the OP used this site the error could not be located*. Way more useful is using http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ as it will point to line 11 with a cursor under `tower`.

Comment: I make the format valid now but still find same error @Deepak